# Optional groups in a regular expression

Tags: regex

For some reason I fail to write a correct regular expression to match the following strings:

```
a/b/c/d:d0/d1/d2/d3/:e;f'

a/b/c/d:d0/:e;f'

a/b/c/d:d0/:e'

a/b/c/d:d0'
```

In each string the `c` and `e` should be extracted. As you see, `e` is optional and the last string doesn't contain it. In that case the regular expression should still match and return the `c`.

This is the expression that I came up with, but it does not support an optional `e`:

```
a\/b\/(?<the_c>\w*)\/.*?\/:(?<the_e>\w*)
```

I thought to make the last part optional, but then it just doesn't find the `e` at all:

```
a\/b\/(?<the_c>\w*)\/.*?(?:\/:(?<the_e>\w*))?
                        ^^^                ^^
```

Here is a link to test out this example: https://regex101.com/r/C2Jkhq/1

What's wrong with my regex here?

Comment: Maybe `a\/b\/(?<the_c>\w*)\/(?:.*\/:(?<the_e>\w*))?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
a\/b\/(?<the_c>\w*)\/(?:.*\/:(?<the_e>\w*))?
```

*Details*:

- `a\/b\/` - `a/b/` string
- `(?<the_c>\w*)` - zero or more word chars captured into "the_c" group
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(?:.*\/:(?<the_e>\w*))?` - an optional sequence (that is tried at least once) matching:

  - `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  - `\/:`  - `/:` string
  - `(?<the_e>\w*)` - zero or more word chars captured into "the_e" group .

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oWFEXH/1).